# what does contributor mean in CNN contributor

Tags: meaning

what does contributor mean in this sentence:

> he is CNN contributor

thanks

Comment: This question could be reopened IF you told us what you found when you looked up “contributor” in a dictionary, and why those definitions didn’t make sense in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person who is a CNN contributor is a person who contributes content to CNN, typically news stories or other information. CNN will use the content in its programs.